# Robocopy exclude folders/subfolders containing a file named nobackup.txt

Tags: robocopy, exclude

We backup a large directory structure but want to exclude some directories.

Is it possible to exclude subfolders when the parent folder contains a file named "nobackup.txt"?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not directly from a Robocopy command. You could use another method to search the directory tree looking for "nobackup.txt" and create a file which lists those directories. You then tell Robocopy to exclude the directories listed in that file.